# Rails 6, Angular 11 Can't resolve all parameters for Component: (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to start new app with rails 6 and angular 11

I created my app:

`rails new my_app`

`rails webpacker:install:angular`

`yarn add html-loader`

I started the app and I got 'Hello Angular'
But when I try to inlcude a module into my component, I get an error in browser:

`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).`

I didn't forget to import the module in the component

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import template from './app.component.html'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template: template
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular!';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    const self = this;

    // self.http.get('/api/v1/dashboard').subscribe(
    //     (response) => { console.log(response) },
    //     (error) => { console.log(error) }
    // )

  }
}
```

and in the module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I imported reflect-metadata in polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';
```

set emitDecoratorMetadata to true in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*", "app/javascript/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "gardening",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing and found this helpful: https://githubmemory.com/repo/rails/webpacker/issues/3102

in combination with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68806961/579018

TL;DR
Use `"ts-loader": "^8.2.0"`