# webpack ts-loader error : loaderContext.getOptions is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to import my typescript file into `webpack`, when I run `tsc` in my terminal everything works fine, But when I  try to use compile my typescript code in `ts-loader` this weird error is shown :

```
ERROR in ./src/Main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
TypeError: loaderContext.getOptions is not a function
    at getLoaderOptions (D:\Projects\Real\AviUI\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:91:41)
    at Object.loader (D:\Projects\Real\AviUI\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:14:21)
```

the webpack version : `4.43.0`, the ts-loader version : `^9.2.3` , the loader-utils version: `^1.4.0`

webpack.config.js file :

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.ts'),
    module: {
        rules: [ 
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            include: [source_path],
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
        }],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'avi_ui.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    externals: {
        'jquery': '`jquery`',
        'angular' : '`angular`'
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

NOTE : I tried to update my `typescript` compiler to latest version(currently latest version is: 4.3.3) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Github](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/595) question the only way to solve this problem is
upgrade the `webpack` to v5.
I found [this](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/) link from webpack official website. The easiest way to upgrade version is using your javascript package manager , for exampele if your using `npm` or `yarn` the following terminal codes can be used :

```bash
# using npm 
$ npm install webpack@5.75.0
# using yarn
$ yarn add webpack@5.75.0
```

NOTE: In this time current version of `webpack` is **5.75.0**

Comment: I am having this issue with Webpack 5 also. I have ts-loader 9.2.6 and webpack 5.69.1 installed.

Comment: If you're running `webpack` from the command line then run `webpack --version` to confirm the version you're running is v5+. I had v5 installed in my project but v4 installed globally and so was accidentally running my build with the wrong version.

Comment: cypress/webpack-preprocessor use webpack 4, you will get an error if use webpack 5

Answer (score 58):

There is one more way to solve the problem, in addition to upgrading your webpack to webpack 5, as Ali Bigdeli's answer pointed out. You can also just downgrade ts-loader to 8.2.0. Using your package manager of choice, that might look like:

```sh
npm install ts-loader@~8.2.0
```

As pointed out in the [Github question](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/595#issuecomment-827253722)
linked by Ali Bigdeli, the last version of `ts-loader` that supports webpack 4 is 8.2.0, and if you want to receive patches to this version, you can depend on the semver ~8.2.0 version.

Comment: it would be easier to downgrade `ts-loader` than to upgrade `webpack` i guess

Comment: Thank you! This was the magic version number I needed! I had been looking at the peerDependencies which said webpack * all the way up to 9.2.1. In my case, upgrading to webpack 5 would have greatly increased the scope of my work as it'd affect other things like react-scripts and jest which I'd prefer to upgrade later.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeMike, this helped me to save a lot of time. Version [8.3.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/releases/tag/v8.3.0) also allows solving this issue.

Comment: Version 8.4.0 works as well.