# Webpack 5 babel-loader tsx error "TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function"

Tags: webpack, jsx, webpack-5

I am getting the following error with my Webpack 5 config that needs to handle ts and tsx files. There's /ReactScripts with our react tsx/ts files, then all ts files in /Content I am quite new to Webpack and I just can't seem to find any other question that resolves this issue. I'm not sure I even have the best build for this, but I'm trying to make it work. ALL packages are up to date as far as I can tell!:

Error:

`ERROR in ./ReactScripts/AppRoot.tsx Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function`

webpack.config.ts:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

function vendorBundle( bundle ) {
    if ( bundle ) {
        return {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "initial"
                    }
                }
            },
            sideEffects: false,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin(),
            ],
        };
    }
    else {
        return {};
    }
}

function WebpackConfiguration(WebpackOptions, mode)
{  
    return {
        watchOptions: {
            poll: true,
            ignored: "/node_modules",
        },
        context: __dirname,
        mode: mode,
        stats: { modules: false, errorDetails: true },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".tsx"],
            fallback: {
                fs: false,
                "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
                "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
                "buffer": require.resolve("buffer"),
                "url": require.resolve("url"),
                "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") ,
                "util": require.resolve("util"),
                "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            }
        },
        entry: {
            // common ts and js files
            initial: path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/initial.entry.ts"),
            slickgrid: path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/slickgrid.entry.ts"),
            jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/jquery.entry.ts"),
            scriptsadmin: path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/scriptsadmin.entry.ts"),
            main: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/tscore.entry.ts"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/jqx.entry.ts"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/tswidgets.entry.ts"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/managers.entry.ts"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/thirdparty.entry.ts"), path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/main.entry.ts")],
            lbcomponents: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Scripts/LBComponents/dist/lb-components.min.js"),
            ie7: path.resolve(__dirname, "./TEST_ENTRY/ie7.entry.ts"),

            // react js and jsx files
            reactAppRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, "./ReactScripts/AppRoot.tsx"),            
        },
        output: {
            path:  WebpackOptions.BuildDirectory,
            filename: "[name].bundle.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: "process/browser",
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              $: "jquery",
              jQuery: "jquery"
            }),
        ],
        performance: {
            hints: false
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                // ts/x files
                {
                    test: /\.ts(x)$/,
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "Content"),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "ReactScripts"),
                    ],
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'babel-loader',
                        {
                            loader: "ts-loader",
                            options: {
                                transpileOnly: true,
                                experimentalWatchApi: true
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },
                // images
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
                    type: "asset",
                },
                // handles mjs files from node_modules
                {
                    test: /\.mjs$/,
                    include: /node_modules/,
                    type: "javascript/auto",
                    resolve: {
                        fullySpecified: false
                    }
                },
            ]
        },

        // build source maps for us to use in dev
        devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",

        // builds vendor bundle (npm) and optimizes
        optimization: vendorBundle( WebpackOptions.VendorBundle ),
    }
}

module.exports = WebpackConfiguration;
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./TEST/types",
    "declarationMap": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "es6", "dom" ]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser":  true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "Scripts/LBComponents"
  ]
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "ignore": [ "node-modules/**" ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "2"
        //,"debug": true,
        //"targets": {
        //  "browsers": [ "IE >= 11" ]
        //}
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Layout.cshtml:

`@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/TEST/initial.bundle.js")` and the like, one line for each bundle above

Comment: you might have forgot to install the loader you're trying to use, for example `babel-loader`, WebPack loaders are not built-in to the lib, they are like plugins that needs to be installed and part of your `package.json`, see similar question: [webpack ts-loader error : loaderContext.getOptions is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68016372/webpack-ts-loader-error-loadercontext-getoptions-is-not-a-function). The loaders are typically the ones defined in the `rules` section